# Installing Ubuntu on a Win 10 Lenovo with 5 partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lenovo

I would like to install Ubuntu (maybe 18 or 20) to achieve a dual-boot with Windows 10 Home, which is already installed by manufacturer. The pc is a oldish Lenovo IdeaPad 100 15IBY (4 Gb RAM, Intel Pentium 2,16 GHz with 4 cores). Maybe some of you can suggest me a good release of Ubuntu.

I've already done this procedure years ago, I know more or less what I need to to, but last time I erased all of my HDD and I don't want to repeat the same story.

The problem is about the number of partitions: from factory, there is a C: Win of 400 GB, D: "Lenovo" of 25 GB, then some more smaller partitions which are supposed to be for recovery. I never liked this stuff of having a small D: called Lenovo with useless things on it.

So what I did is, after backup of important files from C: Windows  :

1. Deleted the Volume D: Lenovo of 25 Gb
2. Shrinked the C: Volume, removing 35 Gb from it
3. Now I have 60 Gb unallocated space, where I want to install Ubuntu.

Those operations were made with Windows 10 homemade partitioning tool, and this is the screenshot of the actual partitions.

[image: partitions]

By going to another Windows 10 system tool, I see that the physical disk is only one (disk#0), so they are only "virtual" partitions (I mean, no more than one physical HDD in the laptop).

I'm afraid about the 2 more partitions which are on the RIGHT of the unallocated space, as I red online that what's on the right may be destroyed ( is that real)? Then I also read also about changing the drive mode from RAID to AHCI. Is this about the whole disk or is it something one can change for only one partition (or unallocated part?)

Should I choose a format for the unallocated space before trying to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you boot from the Ubuntu installation USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option? If it works, open the app Gparted. and take a screenshot. Then edit your question above and add the screenshot to your question.

Comment: I would like to add that I saw online that one can have a partition to put files which are then shared between the Win 10 and Ubuntu OSs... I should prepare this partition now?

Comment: @user68186 : I ' m still preparing the USB, perhaps can you suggest me a good stable Ubuntu release which fits with the laptop specs and the free space I put? Thanks

Comment: That partition would be your D: drive.  You should have kept it if you wanted a shared partition.

Comment: Lubuntu or Xubuntu would work better for your old laptop.

Comment: thank you @user68186... 1) Couldn't I just re-create a D partition for shared files? 2) and what about a Debian linux?

Comment: Ubuntu has different products, those using the *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18, Ubuntu Core 20) are *snap* only and not related to the more common *yy.mm* format releases (eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop). You mention 18 & 20 where you likely mean 18.04 & 20.04 which are different products, so please be precise.  All *yy* releases are intended for headless use (no screen) though yes you can add a desktop - it's still not the same as an actual desktop system...

Comment: Debian is off-topic here as only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, but note: in testing Lubuntu 18.04 LTS & Debian 10 (Buster) on boxes as old as from 2003; Lubuntu actually outperformed Debian on the lowest-powered system (on others the difference was minimal/none)

Comment: yes sorry guys, thank you, forgot that debian is off-topic here.  I don't think my laptop is that old, I'll see if installing Xubuntu 20 or ubuntu 14 or 16... However my main issue is what to do with those others Win 10 partitions, the smaller ones on the right, are them safely protected while installing ubuntu?

Comment: Xubuntu is a desktop release (and is *deb* package based) so all releases are *yy.mm* in format, the oldest supported & on-topic on this site is Xubuntu 18.04 LTS. Ubuntu uses *yy* releases as *snap* only and they don't come with desktops (though can use GNOME which is available as a *snap*; but XFCE as used by Xubuntu is not). The installer will only do whatever you tell it to do, which includes completely overwriting whatever existed on your system before hand, so you should always have backups & tell it exactly what you want (you control what is used, touched or erased).

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu 14.04 is beyond it's standard support (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/) so is off-topic here, and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is about to reach the same point (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) so I'd not recommend that (unless you're willing to use ESM which may require paying for support; I'd instead suggest a *standard* support release that is on-topic here).

Comment: Is this one of the odd systems that is 64 bit, but requires 32 bit UEFI? They tried that to make it Windows only as back then Linux did not have a 32 bit UEFI. Older info, but should be same issues, if 32 bit UEFI. LENOVO Ideapad 100 Laptop 16.04 Dual Boot 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336544
LENOVO Ideapad 100S Laptop  32 bit UEFI bootia32.efi
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350606

Comment: Finally I had succesfully installed Ubuntu Mate 20.04, via USB, here what I've done: 1) Disabled Fast Boot, Safe Boot and Hybernate from Windows 10; 2) write out the memory size of the unallocated part of the disk , so you can recognize it when asked for; 3) Choosed that part for the installation, formatted it as ext4 , with mount point as root (/) ; 4) Selected the same partition also for the Dual Boot installation, not another one ; 5) When I turn on the laptop, it correctly ask me to choose in beetween Ubuntu and Windows 10.

Comment: @marcoAriman your last comment should have been written up as an ANSWER, please do so.